# Error 400 happened while getting response from uri

Tags: asp.net, uri

I have problem with use of URL. There is a bug related to web API. I need to update data in database using rest APIs. But the URL I have to update the data in database is throwing error:

```
“The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request”.
```

so I am not understanding whether it's wrong with my code or with URL I have. So please suggest your ideas regarding this.

Comment: you have to provide your code to make the question more clear

Comment: Show the code from where you call this API.

Comment: Its like i am placing HTTP get request call to URL and while getting response from that URL  it is throwing that error.